# How to get header image to be responsive while also not moving down

Tags: html, css

I've been working with HTML and CSS for a very short time and took on a project for my school. I'm currently building a website for our art fair! I've stumbled upon an issue where when I resize my tab the header image seems to shrink incorrectly. You can also only see it properly if on a 1080p screen.

I was wondering how I would resize the header to move consistently when shrinking/expanding the page or increasing/decreasing the resolution of the screen. I made a fiddle so you can have easy access to my code.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lucasizq/nu7fLr1k/7/

```
.mainphoto {
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 50px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  z-index: -100;
}
```

This is where I think my error is, but I am unsure.

Answer (score 0):

Change your rules to

```css
.mainphoto{
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 0;
    top:0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100% ;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -100;
}
```

**explaining**

To lock it on top

> padding-top: 0;
>
> top:0;

To forces the img to be responsive inside it's fathers container

> width: 100%

To keep the same aspect ratio (not to shrink the image)

> height: auto;

**tip**

paint body background to the sabe background color as the img so it will look seemless when the img resize down too much (like for mobile screens)

check it out: https://jsfiddle.net/u6fg1v2t/

Comment: I went ahead and made the changes, however now the image seems to move down on a 1440p screen, and on a 1080p screen it also moves down and as the buttons and the h1 over it. Is there any way that I can lock it to the top and make sure the buttons and h1 stay under it ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to put main photo as, logo or for showing as image in the content, so I have added it in both section so you can comment it and make this work as you want.

Also you should be careful with html semantics, you are adding everything to header while only nav should be there and other outside of it in the content div/section. You can read about html semantics here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp

Here is the working code as per my understanding of your question. Let me know if there are any confusions or questions, I will be glad to help you anytime.

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "montserrate", sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-color: #000000;
}

.logo {
  height: 80px;
  width: 100px;
}

header {
  height: 80px;
}

.nav {
  padding: 0 10px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

ul {
  float: right;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 20px;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px 5px;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  color: #D8C7C7;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #D8C7C7;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
}

ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #47b8f7;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #47b8f7;
  color: fff;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  /* top: 350px; */
  flex: 1;
}

.content h1 {
  font-size: 52px;
  margin: 25px;
}

.main-photo {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}

.festival-attraction-menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.btn {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 7px 28px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
}

.btn1:hover {
  background-color: #47b8f7;
  border: 2px solid #47b8f7;
}

.btn2:hover {
  background-color: #ffe713;
  border: 2px solid #ffe713;
}

.btn3:hover {
  background-color: #ffe713;
  border: 2px solid #ffe713;
}

.btn4:hover {
  background-color: #FF00A9;
  border: 2px solid #FF00A9;
}

@media screen and (max-width:960px) {}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {}

@media screen and (max-width:480px) {}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>WWHS Festival of The Arts</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styleHomepage.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <header class="header-section">
    <div class="nav">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/zISS0nU.png" alt="FOA" class="logo">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="content">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/zISS0nU.png" alt="FOA" class="main-photo">
    <h1>FESTIVAL OF THE ARTS</h1>

    <div class="festival-attraction-menu">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn1">Digital Art</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn2">Photo</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn3">Ceramics</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn4">Coffee House</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```